# C# compressing an image to 10KB

Tags: c#, image, compression

I am writing a program in C# that involves image compression. I need to be able to take any picture and compress it so that it is less than 10KB. Quality is not a huge concern, but I would like to keep as much as possible. I have searched for and tried numerous solutions. Any of the ones I have found cannot resize to a specific size and even with iteration, reach maximum compression much before 10KB. Also it would be great if it was open source or free!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: An easy would would be representing the image in a format that doesn't add any compression, calculate how many pixels you can represent in the largest file <10 KiB of this format and width:height ratio (taking into account headers etc.), and then scale down to that size. It's possible to do better with compressing file formats but I have no idea how to do this reliably. It's also possible that, for some images, the compression fails to give any space advantage.

Comment: ALright, thanks for the tip, I'll look into it.

Comment: Please also show any work/research you've done up thill this point.

Comment: Depending on how important color is, you can save a whole lot of space by reducing the number of colors used. For example, you can make an image 1/3 the size (in bytes) by converting a 24 bpp image to 8 bpp using a halftone pallete. You could get a little better quality by examining the image first and constructing a pallete for that image based on the colors that it contains.

Comment: Calculate the average color. That compresses it to 3 bytes!